# Use of display:none but still keep the space used

Tags: html, css

I have a span with `display:none` but still need its height & width, is there a way to achieve it without changing the display or using `visibility:hidden`?

```css
.mySpan{
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="personName" name="personName" />
  <br/>
  <span class="mySpan">Text that can be displayed or not</span>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Last name</label>
  <input type="text" id="personLastName" name="personLastName" />
  <br/>
  <span class="mySpan">Text that can be displayed or not</span>
</div>
```

I need the height of the span so that there's always a distance between divs like in `visibility=hidden`.

Comment: You need to explain us why you do not want to use visibility:hidden which the THE way to do what you want

Comment: wrap span into another element and set width and height –

Comment: You can use `opacity: 0`, but any contents inside will still be intractable. You can click text, etc..

Comment: @mplungjan I need to keep the space so the user doesn't see any change on the visualization like the last name label going down because an extra text appeared below the name

Comment: I understand - why is visibility not the answer you want? If you space it out, you will have a movement if the full span wraps content - see my answer for a solution I guess is what you are looking for

Comment: `display:none` does not take any space, probably you have padding or margins between columns

Comment: I have this question too. I don't want to use a span or visibility either (I reasons why I don't want to), and none of these anwser the question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`display:none;` does NOT take any space, as you can see in your own snippet.  `visibility: hidden` however, DOES use the empty space.

```css
.mySpan1 {
display: none; 
}
.mySpan2 {
visibility: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<div>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" id="personName" name="personName" />
<br/>
<span class="mySpan1">Text that can be displayed or not</span> text after display: none
</div>
<div>
<label>Last name</label>
<input type="text" id="personLastName" name="personLastName" />
<br/>
<span class="mySpan2">Text that can be displayed or not</span> text after visibility: hidden;
</div>
```

Addition: If you want the empty space without using `visibility: hidden`, you can just create a tag with only `&nbsp;` as its content and no extra display parameter

Comment: OP mentioned he doesn't want to use `visibility:hidden`

Comment: Yeah using `&nbsp;` inside a span worked fine, thanks!

Comment: That will not work if the text when full is larger than one linespace height

Comment: @mplungjan is ok for me, won't be larget than 1 linespace.

Comment: Still does not make any sense to manipulate the DOM when you can just change visibility

Answer (score 3):

The [visibility:hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) IS what you are looking for - there are not good reasons for not using that.

You cannot have `display:none` AND have the element take up space

> The box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is drawn), but still affects layout.  Descendants of the element will be visible if they have visibility:visible (this doesn't work in IE up to version 7).

Here is a script that manipulates an error span - I assume that is what you actually want

Using delegation and DRY

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const toggleError = (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (!tgt.matches(".nameField")) return;
    const errorSpan = document.getElementById(tgt.getAttribute("data-error"));
    errorSpan.style.visibility = e.type === "focusout" && tgt.value.trim() === "" ? "visible" : "hidden";
  };
  const container = document.getElementById("container");
  container.addEventListener("focusout", toggleError);
  container.addEventListener("focusin", toggleError);
});
```

```css
.mySpan {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="nameField" id="personName" name="personName" data-error="fNameSpan" />
    <br/>
    <span class="mySpan" id="fNameSpan">Please enter a first name</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Last name</label>
    <input type="text" class="nameField" id="personLastName" name="personLastName" data-error="lNameSpan" />
    <br/>
    <span class="mySpan" id="lNameSpan">Please enter a last name</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Older version from when the question was asked

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var fields = document.querySelectorAll(".nameField");
  for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    fields[i].onblur = function() {
      document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("data-error"))
        .style.visibility = this.value.trim() == "" ? "visible" : "hidden";
    }
    fields[i].onfocus = function() {
      document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("data-error")).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.mySpan {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="nameField" id="personName" name="personName" data-error="fNameSpan" />
  <br/>
  <span class="mySpan" id="fNameSpan">Please enter a first name</span>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Last name</label>
  <input type="text" class="nameField" id="personLastName" name="personLastName" data-error="lNameSpan" />
  <br/>
  <span class="mySpan" id="lNameSpan">Please enter a last name</span>
</div>
```

Comment: OP mentioned he doesn't want to use `visibility:hidden`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it into another  like the snippet as follows,

```css
.mySpan{
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="personName" name="personName" />
  <br/>
  <span><span class="mySpan">Text that can be displayed or not</span>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Last name</label>
  <input type="text" id="personLastName" name="personLastName" />
  <br/>
  <span><span class="mySpan">Text that can be displayed or not</span>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish exactly, but i guess `opacity:0` will do the job. `display:none` removes element from document flow, while `visibility:hidden` maintains the box model of the element.